# fastapi body behaving differently between two functions

Tags: python, fastapi

I have two functions and I'm using similar parameters but for one they work as expected and for the other, they do not:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Header, HTTPException, Body

@app.post("/portfolio/analytics/carbon-footprint", dependencies=[Depends(api_counter)])
async def getPortfolioCarbonFootprint(
    tickers: list = Body(...),
    func: str = Body(...),
    http_client: aiohttp.ClientSession = fastapi.Depends(http_client)
):
  
    print(tickers)
    return res

#historical prices
@app.post("/portfolio/analytics/historicalprices", dependencies=[Depends(api_counter)])
async def getPortfolioHistoricalPrices(
    tickers: list = Body(...),
    http_client: aiohttp.ClientSession = fastapi.Depends(http_client)
):
  
    print(tickers)
    jsonResults = await getHistoricalPrices(tickers)
    return jsonResults
```

For both I send it this json:

```
{"tickers" : [ "IBM.US", "MSFT.US"]}
```

the first function works perfectly. The second returns this error:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body"
            ],
            "msg": "value is not a valid list",
            "type": "type_error.list"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's where it gets weird. If I send this:

```
[ "IBM.US", "MSFT.US"]
```

then it works as expected.

So function 1, works fine. Function 2 is copied from function 1 and it doesn't accept tickers as input but sending it a raw list works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two functions is the number of parameters to be filled in by the user. In the first function you have `tickers` and `func`, and in the second one you only have `tickers`.

From the FastAPI documentation:

> But if you have only a single item body parameter from a Pydantic model Item.
>
> By default, FastAPI will then expect its body directly.
>
> But if you want it to expect a JSON with a key item and inside of it the model contents, you can use the special Body parameter embed

So in the second function, if you want to have a key, you must write:

```
tickers: list = Body(..., embed=True)
```